# When Installing 2019 Visual Studio Community, how to add C# templates?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've installed Visual Studio Community 2019 on Windows 10, but I can't find any C# templates - ones like WinForms and Console Application are nowhere to be found.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you select a C# [workload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) when installing?

Comment: Please do some research by yourself before asking the question.

Comment: That's what you see when you try to add a new item to a solution.  Be sure to add to a *project* instead.  Use File > New > Project if you haven't done so yet.

Comment: Yes I did. This problem was earlier

Comment: Rechecked it, for the install. Will see. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it works. But clicking on Form.cs in a project must call template codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to modify the visual studio installer like below
[image]

Then, you have to install .Net desktop development like below
[image]

Comment: ... If the OP wants to do C# desktop development in WPF, Winforms, or console apps. One would hope that the the OP would read the descriptions and make informed decisions, but I'm not sure how they missed this screen while installing the first time ...

Comment: While installing the first time web apps selected as default, others won't .

Comment: we need to customize while install, if not, later we can modify and customize based on our need

Comment: Yes, there were these windows during the install. Thanks. But I choosed this, no C# is visible

Answer (score 2):

### You're adding items to a solution, not creating a new project.

The screenshot you've shown is of the list showing items you can add. To create a new project, you either have to go to `File > New > Project` or press the `Create a new project` button on the homepage.

If you've installed any .NET modules, C# project templates should show up there.

If you still can't see any, open the Visual Studio Installer, make sure you're on the `Installed` tab, and click `Modify` on `Visual Studio Community 2019`.

Then, after making sure you're on the `Workloads` tab, tick `.NET desktop developement`, then click `Modify` at the bottom-right.

Once you've done all that, you should be able to find plenty of C# project templates, as well as VB and F# ones.

Comment: works, but on Form.cs in a project must we get any code?

Comment: @user2543953 I'm sorry, but I don't really know much about WinForms. You should probably ask a new question for that.
And also, please mark this as the selected answer if it works.